# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_federated.python.simulation' has no attribute 'HDF5ClientData'

Tags: python, tensorflow-federated

I have a dataset written to an h5 file, and I want to convert it to**tff.simulation.datasets.ClientData**,That is, after pre-processing it becomes this form **<tensorflow_federated.python.simulation.datasets.client_data.PreprocessClientData at 0x7f00947f6f50>**.
A week ago, I was able to read it with this

```
train_path='FederatedClients/dataTrain.h5'
train_data = tff.simulation.HDF5ClientData(train_path)
```

but now, I get the following error with this statement again.

```
----------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-f4c34c62ca50> in <module>
      1 train_path='FederatedClients/dataTrain.h5'
      2 #train_data=pd.read_hdf(train_path)
----> 3 train_data = tff.simulation.HDF5ClientData(train_path)
      4 test_path='FederatedClients/dataTest.h5'
      5 test_data=pd.read_hdf(test_path)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_federated.python.simulation' has no attribute 'HDF5ClientData'
```

I don't know what to do anymore, I use the most basic panda to read the H5 file and I also get the  error, TAT

```
train_data=pd.read_hdf(train_path)
```

```
----------------------------------------------------------
ValueError               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-151fe098668c> in <module>
      1 train_path='FederatedClients/dataTrain.h5'
----> 2 train_data=pd.read_hdf(train_path)
      3 train_data = tff.simulation.HDF5ClientData(train_path)
      4 test_path='FederatedClients/dataTest.h5'
      5 test_data=pd.read_hdf(test_path)

~/anaconda3/envs/tff/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in read_hdf(path_or_buf, key, mode, errors, where, start, stop, columns, iterator, chunksize, **kwargs)
    437             if len(groups) == 0:
    438                 raise ValueError(
--> 439                     "Dataset(s) incompatible with Pandas data types, "
    440                     "not table, or no datasets found in HDF5 file."
    441                 )

ValueError: Dataset(s) incompatible with Pandas data types, not table, or no datasets found in HDF5 file.
```

I would be grateful if you could solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

TFF version `0.19.0` removed `tff.simulation.HDF5ClientData` ([release notes](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/releases/tag/v0.19.0)). TFF datasets are now backed by SQLite instead of HDF5.

The HDF5 implementation could be recovered from https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/v0.18.0/tensorflow_federated/python/simulation/hdf5_client_data.py. Copying that locally and replacing:

- `client_data.ClientData` with `tff.simulation.datasets.ClientData`.
- Remove `py_typecheck` and `tensor_utils` usage, they are not necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But when I did what you said, I had other error【----------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-c38025bbc72a> in <module>
      1 train_path='FederatedClients/dataTrain.h5'
      2 #train_data=pd.read_hdf(train_path)
----> 3 train_data = HDF5ClientData(train_path)
      4 test_path='FederatedClients/dataTest.h5'
      5 test_data=pd.read_hdf(test_path)

TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class HDF5ClientData with abstract methods serializable_dataset_fn】

Comment: I  copy that locally and replace,when I use"train_path='FederatedClients/dataTrain.h5'
train_data = HDF5ClientData(train_path)", the above error occurs. QAQ Thank you again for answering my confusion!!!

Comment: Hello, do you know why this error occurred? Again, I would like to ask for your help, thank you very much!!